# How do I allow page breaks between list elements, but not inside them?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I know it is possible to keep MS Word from inserting a page break in the middle of a paragraph. Now, however, when trying that with list elements, it takes the whole list as a paragraph.

I want it to allow page breaks between list elements, but not inside them. Right now it only allows them at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two related settings for paragraphs: "keep with next" and "keep lines together".

It sounds like you want "keep lines together" on and "keep with next" off. This will keep all lines of a list paragraph on the same page, but will permit the list as a whole to split across pages.

You should be able to modify the List Paragraph style so that this setting applies to all your list items.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For some reason this didn't work at first. If I remember correctly, I had also checked another option in this dialog box or modified some styling for the actual paragraph instead of the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Keep with Next will not work as expected if there is an image or a text box anchored between the heading and the following paragraph (i.e. at the start of the paragraph). Presumably Word interprets the anchor rather than the paragraph as the next item, but then fails to actually keep the heading with either.
Move the anchor point to the second paragraph after the heading and the heading will then correctly jump to teh same page as the intended first paragraph.